# Excel: How to color the weekends with concatenated date and conditional formating

Tags: excel, formatting

I have created a timesheet where the year and month is concatenated in a cel and where the dates fills the first column. The day dates start with "1" in cel A6 and the second date is a formula "=A6 + 1". Plain and simple. But now I would like to color only the weekends in grey. I've searched on the internet and in the timesheets that I had but in Excel 2016 it won't work. Could anyone help me please?

It looks like this:

```
    Day  | Start    |  Stop       | lunch      |Total hours     |
    1      09:00      17:30           0:30         08:00
    2
    3
    4      09:15      17:30           0:15         08:00
    5      09:00      17:30           0:30         08:00
    6      09:00      17:30           0:30         08:00
    7      09:00      17:30           0:30         08:00
    8      09:15      17:30           0:15         08:00
    9      09:00      17:30           0:30         08:00
    10
```

etc...
I've tried:

```
    =WEEKDAG(DATUM($H$1;$H$2;$A$6);2) > 5
```

where WEEKDAG = Weekday, Datum = date, H1 and H2 are the Year and the Month. but it doesn't work. Nothing happens actually. I've tried to leave the dollar sign on the column A$6 but it doesn't work neither. I've tried to change the format of the cells in General, text and numbers, no chance....
Please advice?

Comment: Which days are weekend days?

Comment: Check your "applies to" range - It should start with the first cell, is that A6? Remove $ signs from A6 reference and use just `=WEEKDAG(DATUM($H$1;$H$2;A6);2) > 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this with the same setup as you. The first date is a regular date all subsequent dates are A9+1.

I use these two different conditional formatting statements. One for Saturday (7) and one for Sunday (1).

```
=WEEKDAY($A9)=7 =WEEKDAY($A9)=1
```

Click Conditional Formatting
New Rule
Use a formula to determine which cells to format
Paste your formula
Select your formatting
Click Ok
Repeat for the second formula.
Apply the formatting to the appropriate range.

The $a9 in my samples should point to your first date. This method is specifically testing the weekday number against the value in your formula (0 or 7).

Comment: Hi Tim, this doesn't work for me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. but nothing is collouring.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear that this is two separate cond. formatting statements. One is going to test the cell for Saturday and the second is testing for Sunday. If you put both tests in one statement it won't work. Select the cell you want to format, click Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", then enter one of the tests (=weekday($A9)=7), then set your format and click OK. Repeat that for testing for 0. The formatting for the selected cell will be dependent on the cell referred to in the formula (cell a9 in this example).

Comment: yes, that's what I did, but it colors all the cells, from 1 up to 31...? I only did if for"7" and everything is colored. any idea?

Comment: Hang on, are the values in the day column actual dates or just integers of the day or the month? This formula will work on a value like 3/8/19 but not on 8. Well, it will work, but not correctly. I'll add a another answer to try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

OK, review this information and create a sample on a clean sheet to avoid any unknowns.

Create a spreadsheet like this.... You don't need the third column, that's just for illustration.

[image]

Then your Conditional formatting dialog should look like this...

[image]

The formula in the conditional formatting dialog should look like this.

Hopefully this helps. It's easy once you get the hang of it. You can extend this to things like formatting every other row/column, etc.
[image]

Comment: Hello Tim, thanks for the effort! But could you elaborate on your statements please? You mention 'weekday($A2)=1', but for what day should it stand for? Is that the first day of the week? Because in your excel sheet I see that your weekends are on the 7th and 1st day of the week. (well, that is in Belgium standards  ;-)  I guess in your place these days are weekend days? ) Nevertheless, how many "weekday($AX)=1" should I have? 7 in total? where is "weekday($A1)=1"?  Should I still use your previous answer for the weekends like  "=WEEKDAY($A9)=7" and 
" =WEEKDAY($A9)=1". thanks in advance.

Comment: The weekday function defaults to 1=Sunday and 7=Saturday. There are several optional return_types. Ex., =weekday($a$2,2) would start the week on Monday and end on Sunday.  There are options to start he week on any day of the week you'd like. You should only need two separate conditional formatting statements. One is =weekday($a2)=1 (for sundays) and the other =weekday($a2)=7 (for saturdays). When you are entering the formats, does the preview box say "No Format Set" or does it show a sample like above? You have to define the format (bold, fill, outline, etc) by clicking the Format button.

Comment: Start typing weekday formula in a cell, when you see excel auto fill in the edit bar, double click on "weekday", that will bring up help and show you the optional return_types.

Comment: Hi Tim, I've got it now. Thanks a lot. But it's a shame that I can't use the date concatenated, because by doing so I can make a template out of it and just change the month or year and re-use the spreadsheet over and over again. But thanks anyways.

Comment: If you are concatenating text into a date you probably need to wrap it in datevalue so it's converted from a string to a serial date. The easiest way to tell is to select the cell with the formula, in the edit bar select the formula and press the F9 key, that will evaluate the formula. If it shows something like "4/9/2019" that means it's a text value. if it shows 43564 it's a serial date value.